# As of 2016, which has been the last Type-Moon work that's contained explicit content?

Tags: type-moon

A recent question made me realize something. Type-Moon's early works like *Tsukihime* and *Fate/Stay Night* had explicit scenes in them. However, some of their recent works such as *Fate/Extra*, *Mahoutsukai no Yoru* and the many re-releases of *Fate/Stay Night* have actually had none of this.

So I have been wondering: As of 2016, what was the last work Type-Moon released that contained explicit content? Have there been any social factors which may have forced Type-Moon to cease adding explicit content in their works?

Kinoko Nasu first started Type-Moon as a doujin group, so I also include any Type-Moon released doujinshi they may have released (if there are any) which contained explicit content.

By explicit content, I mean graphic or deeply detailed sexual content which would be restricted to adults only. I don't count stuff like in *Fate/Extra*, such as

> In the nurse's office when Hakuno Kishinami's Servant is being recharged by Rin/Rani, there is an implication they may be having sex. (Though I only saw Rin and Saber's scene. Not sure about Archer or Caster, but I assume it's more or less the same.)

Or in the *Strawberry Panic* Light Novel (which isn't Type-Moon), where

> Yaya dreams she's having sex with Hikari and some of the language in that (when Hikari climaxes) I would have thought would only appear in 18/21+ adult content.

Neither of these was restricted to adults only (can't remember *Fate/Extra*'s rating, but *Strawberry Panic* was marketed towards teens as per the rating on the back of the book).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note: this answer assumes that "*graphic or deeply detailed sexual content which would be restricted to adults only*" means **R-18/CERO Z** in Japan.

---

#### Games

Surprisingly, [Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/TYPE-MOON#%E5%95%86%E6%A5%AD%E7%A7%BB%E8%A1%8C%E5%BE%8C%E3%81%AE%E3%82%B2%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A0%E5%B1%95%E9%96%8B) mentioned this,

> 2005年10月28日発売の『Fate/hollow ataraxia』以降アダルトゲームの新規発表は行われていない。
>
> Since the release of *Fate/hollow ataraxia* on 28 Oct 2005, there's no announcement on new adult games.

So, at least that's the answer to the last game containing explicit content: *Fate/hollow ataraxia* (the original PC version, not the PS Vita one).

After that, they started releasing console games only (except *Mahoutsukai no Yoru* for PC as mentioned on the question) with *Fate/EXTRA CCC* having the highest rating of CERO D (R-17, no international release).

#### Anime, Movie & OVA

Since almost all of them were broadcasted on the TV, then they could be considered as 一般向けアニメ (*ippan muke anime*, anime for the general public) even though they might include heavy ecchi scenes (e.g. *Fate/kaleid liner Prisma Illya* ).

This is also true for movies such as *Kara no Kyoukai*, *Fate/stay night UBW*, and also *Carnival Phantasm* OVA.

#### Manga & Light Novel

Some manga were published by Kadokawa, and as far as I know, Kadokawa doesn't publish adult manga (aka. hentai) although, again, they *might* include heavy ecchi scenes.

I can't comment on books under Type-Moon label itself though.

#### Music & Drama CDs

I *believe* all music CDs are clean, but I can't comment on drama CDs.

---

As a matter of fact, only *Fate/stay night* and *Fate/hollow ataraxia* games require age checking on [the official Type-Moon website](http://typemoon.com/game/).

Note: Regarding "*Kinoko Nasu first started Type-Moon as a doujin group, so I also include any Type-Moon released doujinshi they may have released (if there are any) which contained explicit content.*", Type-Moon stopped being a doujin circle and instead became a game company in 2003. As a doujin circle, they only released *Tsukihime* and its extra contents. *Fate/stay night* was the first work as a game company.

Answer (score 0):

The most recent explicit Type-Moon content I'm aware of is the scene from 10:00 to 11:20 in the *Fate/kaleid liner Prisma☆Illya 2wei!* OVA (the hot springs episode).

I don't know if this would be considered explicit by the definition you gave, but it's explicit enough that I'm not willing to post a link or screenshot, or describe the scene in detail.